# Best method for CoffeeScript / LESS autocompilation?

Tags: command-line, css, less, coffeescript

I've been using LESS and CoffeeScript substantially lately, and wondering what would be the best method of monitoring. Currently I use LESS.app, which works great, but I don't think there's a solution for CoffeeScript out there. So, I fall back to CLI. Which isn't entirely inappropriate considering some of the path commands go to different directories, rather than compiling side by side. Also, I imagine running LESS.app over a network (SSH into a different box) won't be fun, even though the growl notifications are nice.

I'm thinking instead I'll just run the CS and LESS watch commands in Node.s script registered to node-forever. node-forever has bit me in the butt once before leaking memory.

So, what are others out there doing? Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think anyone has yet built something like LESS.app for CoffeeScript. But CoffeeScript's command line interpreter does include `watch` functionality:

```
coffee -cwo js coffee
```

will continuously compile everything from the `coffee` directory into the `js` directory, recompiling whenever something changes. (Note that it does *not* detect new files.)

I created a command line utility called [Jitter](https://github.com/TrevorBurnham/Jitter/) that does the same thing with a slightly nicer syntax:

```
jitter coffee js
```

Jitter also has a couple of other nice features; notably, it detects new files and provides Growl notifications if your CoffeeScript contains a syntax error.